# C# constructor gives "Method must have a return type"

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I been trying to learn how to create a class in C#. I created a class and than I tried to create a constructor to go along with the class. But when I created the constructor in the class, the compiler keeps thinking I'm trying to create a method instead.

```
public Product(string code, string description, decimal price)
{
    this.Code = code;
    this.Description = description; 
    this.Price = price;
}
```

> Error 1   Method must have a return type

In my form, I tried to instantiate a object to go along with it.

```
ProductClass product1 = new Product("CS10", "Murach's C# 2010", 54.60m);
```

But it's still giving me an error.

Why isn't my compiler recognizing that I'm trying to create a constructor instead of a method? Is it because I don't have a accessor property to go along with it? Thank you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Constructor` name must be same with the class which it has defined.

If your class name is `ProductClass`, then change your construcor definition as:

```
public ProductClass(string code, string description, decimal price)
    {
        this.Code = code;
        this.Description = description; 
        this.Price = price;
    }
```

Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: @Sayse I agree with you, but it seems that the OP is newbie and I don't want to make him confused.

Comment: Thank you. You sir are a code wizard.